# Mouse click at coordinate with react testing-library user-event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, react-testing-library

*Sarah's mess* is a small hidden object game where players must find her favorite toys inside  a big pile of items. The clicks and coordinates systems are already implemented but I'm eager to test it thoroughly with `user-event` from `testing-library`.

[Sarah's room](https://www.puzzleprime.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/bigstock-Find-Objects-Visual-Game-Solu-72484915-1-1920x1574.jpg)
*I don't own the copy rights of the image and I'm using it for a personal project*

Currently I'm trying to write tests for the click on hidden objects game mechanic. Although, I don't have a clear idea of how to use any of the [Pointer](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/pointer) features the `user-event` library has to offer. So far I've got the following code.

```
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'

it(`render's leaderboard input on success`, async()=>{
  render(<Game/>);
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  await pointer({keys:'[MouseLeft]', target:{`img`,//coordinates}})
})
```

I know that the previous code isn't right but it's the best way I can figure out to draft what I'm trying to achieve. Anyways, my question is:

How can I click at a specific coordinate inside Sarah's room image? My React code works with `MouseEvent.clientX`.

Let me know if you want me to include the code that handles the events

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but maybe something like this could work:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});

it('renders leaderboard input on success', async () => {
  render(<Game/>);

  jest
  .spyOn(window.HTMLElement.prototype, 'getBoundingClientRect')
  .mockImplementation(() => ({
    width: 100,
    left: 0,
    right: 100,
    height: 50,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 50,
  }));

  const img = screen.getByTestId('image');
  await userEvent.pointer({
    keys: '[MouseLeft]',
    target: img,
    coords: { x: 75, y: 42 },
  });

  // ...rest of the test
});
```

We mock `getBoundingClientRect` so that the image element will have a width and height from jsdom's perspective. This should then allow the pointer event to work with the specified mouse coordinates.

Unfortunately this mocks the width+height of *every* html element, which is why I make sure to call `jest.restoreAllMocks()` to at least limit the mock to a single test case.